# Count down Using server DATETIME

Tags: datetime, time, phpmyadmin, countdown

I want to set a contest for a fixed moment to my website. I want to set the 'Begin Time' with date & 'Ending Time' (Only length like *"5 days, 12 hours, 30 minutes"* or full date & time). Using server time A count down timer will appear in the contest page. Before 'Begin Time' will show negative remaining time, In between will show remaining time, After 'Ending time' Timer will be stopped.

I am using phpmyadmin for setting the contest. But I have no Idea about the use of phpmyadmin DATETIME.
How to use DATETIME of phpmyadmin in this case and how to calculate the remaining time from 'Begin time' using current server time?
Thank you.